# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe"); is not working on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, notepad

I'm unable to execute the following from a asp.net web application.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe");

The project builds without errors and it works fine locally. On the live server, it just times out. I spent hours researching this online, only to find that there are others that have had the same problem. So far nothing has worked for me. Most replies seem to suggest looking at permissions. Our IT Director isn't sure how to resolve this  issue either.

Comment: What possible use is it for the client to open notepad on the server? You didn't expect it to open on the client did you? Services are not allowed to interact with the desktop in Windows, so your webserver will never open the notepad UI... Given all of this, I think this question is nonsensical. (It works locally because in all-likelihood, you're running the dev server as administrator in a user-session... a very different environment)

Comment: spender : You can give clients access to executables on a server.  You have to create a group account to allow access and have to set the credentials on the executable to allow the group account.  This should be done in limited cases because you don't want intruders getting onto the server.

Comment: @jdweng Sure, but you'll never see a desktop UI launched from a service though. [It's just not allowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You can make a copy of notepad.exe and put it any where you want.

Comment: @jdweng, I'm pretty sure the OP is expecting notepad.exe to open on the client... which of course is impossible, unless the client and the server are the same machine

Comment: From inside an asp.net to can specify full path where the executable is located.

Answer (score 0):

You probably run the web app on IIS Express locally. That means anything like opening Notepad can work, as it runs under your account in your session.

However, running on full IIS is completely a different thing, as revealed in my blog post,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/04/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis/

Even if Notepad is opened in that way, it is in session 0 on IIS server side, and you cannot see it.

If you attempt to open Notepad in JavaScript at client side, you might also be forbidden to do so, as browsers run client side web apps in sandboxes, which removes access to the operating system resources.

Usually only web apps that explore the security holes in web browsers can launch Notepad by bypassing sandboxing as well as other security protection mechanism, and you probably won't be allowed to do so in a normal web app.